# Windows.Security.Cryptography and Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Tags: encryption, sdk, windows-8, cryptography, windows-phone-8

today i installed the new **windows phone 8 sdk** ([w8phone sdk](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk))... tried to include some of my base classes
from windows 8 apps... same core they say... but whoops?

no `Windows.Security.Cryptography`?

I used the `SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider` for end-to-end encryption of serialized data with WCF Services.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br241537.aspx)

Seems using .NET Framework Encryption is quite proprietary to the platforms/devices.

Anyone some advises for same functionality on **Windows 8 Phone**?

Thanks.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I solved the problem by porting http://www.bouncycastle.org/ to separate Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Libs and a slight changed version of the little BC Engine from here: [Encrypt/Decrypt using Bouncy Castle in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910454/encrypt-decrypt-using-bouncy-castle-in-c-sharp)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`Windows.Security.Cryptography` is a WinRT API. Windows Phone 8 still being mostly Silverlight uses the APIs from `System.Security.Cryptography`, which does not include the `SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider`.

You can still use the [`AesManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) API on Windows Phone, which may, or may not, be enough for your purpose.

`Windows.Security.Cryptography` is most likely just the x86 COM abstraction of the Microsoft cryptolib, which is the same as most of `System.Security.Cryptography` on .NET 3.5-4.0

Comment: Thanks for this voluminous answer. Sure with WP7 compatibility the can't easy go to WinRT API even with the Win8 Core under the hood. But I want also have the same Lib on Server Side with .NET 4.5, not having 3 different implementations for the same encryption purpose. So I stick to my approach having bouncycastle.org compiled for each plattform/device using same methods and signatures.

Comment: And that's indeed a good solution. Optionally, with WP8 now supporting unmanaged code, it should be possible to have a unmanaged implementation of the cryptography algorithms, and such improve performance quite a bit, compared to the fully managed implementations. But it'll probably be some months before we see such projects available on Github et. al.

Comment: AesManaged seems to in System.Security.Cryptography namespace. source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx