# unable to use System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged in windows phone 8 project C#

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8, rijndaelmanaged

I trying to encrypt data in a project but I'm unable to use the System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged in my project.

I tried to create a new application with the specified class and it worked independently. But unluckily unable to add the application to my project.

Next thing I'm gonna try is the portable class, but still have no idea how will that work.

So if you guys know how could I use the System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged in a windows phone 8 project,

Regards,

Also I'm using the AES CBC PKCS7 encryption for additional info, hope for your response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows.Security.Cryptography and Windows Phone 8 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199028/windows-security-cryptography-and-windows-phone-8-sdk) - suggests using the AesManaged class

Comment: microsoft is too stupid to bring some System.Security packages to Windows Phone platform. Still they expects developers to build apps in that platform, that's funny